# Using getline and strtok to extract data from a CSV and storing it in an array results in added newline after last column of a line

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline, strtok, ofstream

im working on a little program which should extract locations and ip-addresses from a csv, storing them in two arrays and then write them back into a config file.
My code is working fine aside from the fact that i get a newline added after each ip-address.
Is there a way to remove it? I tried string::erase but without success.

This is my code:

```
int main()
{
    string use = "test";
    string alias;
    string hostgroup = "allhosts,switches";
    char line[200];
    string hostname_store[100];
    string address_store[100];
    int hostnameCount = 0;
    int addressCount = 0;

    ifstream inputfile("input.csv");

    while (inputfile.getline(line, sizeof line))
    {
        char *token;

        token = strtok(line, ";");

        int counter = 1;

        while (token != nullptr)
        {
            counter++;
            if (counter % 2 == 0)
            {

                hostname_store[hostnameCount] = token;
                hostnameCount++;
            }
            else
            {

                address_store[addressCount] = token;
                addressCount++;
            }

            token = strtok(nullptr, ";");
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {

        if (hostname_store[i] == "")
        {
            cout << "\n";
            break;
        }
        cout << i << ": " << hostname_store[i] << "\n";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        address_store[i].erase(std::remove(address_store[i].begin(), address_store[i].end(), '\n'), address_store[i].cend());
        if (address_store[i] == "")
        {
            cout << "\n";
            break;
        }
        cout << i << ": " << address_store[i] << "\n";
    }

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("example.txt");
    hostgroup = hostgroup + ",defendo_extern";
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {

        if (hostname_store[i] == "")
        {
            break;
        }

        alias = hostname_store[i] + "_extern";

        myfile << "define host {" << endl;
        myfile << "use\t\t\t" << use << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t; Inherit default values from a template" << endl;
        myfile << "hostname\t" << hostname_store[i] << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t; The name we're giving to this switch" << endl;
        myfile << "alias\t\t" << alias << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t; A longer name associated with the switch" << endl;
        myfile << "address\t\t" << address_store[i] << "; IP address of the switch" << endl;
        myfile << "hostgroups\t" << hostgroup << "\t\t\t;Host groups this switch is associated with" << endl;
        myfile << "}" << endl;
        myfile << "\n"
               << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();

}
```

It works fine aside from the output which is like this:

```
define host {
use         test                    ; [description]
hostname    example                 ; [description]
alias       example_extern          ; [description]
address     123.122.123.112
; [description]
hostgroups  allhosts,switches,defendo_extern    ;[description]with
}
```

The CSV looks like this:

```
example;123.123.123.123
example2;123.111.222.123
```

as you can see there is a inserted newline \n after the ip address.
Would be awesome if anyone has a idea how to get rid of it.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please show a [mre] including the input file. Any reason you aren't just using a csv parsing library?

Comment: I didn't have a clue how to use a parsing libary, im not a really pro using C++, its just some selftaught stuff, but if that works better sure i will use it. The CSV is filled like this: example;123.112.123.123

Comment: You'll be glad to hear you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for. It [runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/), this is something that's every C++ developer must know how to do. With your debugger's help you'll able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?